# Using grepl in a nested ifelse statement with other strings

Tags: r, dplyr, grepl

```
#working example
col1 <- c("cat", "cats", "cat2", "dog", "carrot", "carrots", "broccoli", 
"squash", "tundra", "grassland", "grasslands")
df <- as.data.frame(col1)
```

I want to create a new column that identifies whether the string is an animal, vegetable, or biome.

Desired output:

```
         col1      col2
1         cat    animal
2        cats    animal
3        cat2    animal
4         dog    animal
5      carrot vegetable
6     carrots vegetable
7    broccoli vegetable
8      squash vegetable
9      tundra     biome
10  grassland     biome
11 grasslands     biome
```

I'd like to understand why the `grepl` portion of the following code doesn't work.

```
df_new <- df %>% mutate(col2 = ifelse(col1 %in% c("dog", grepl("cat", col1)), "animal", 
     ifelse(col1 %in% c(grepl("carrot", col1), "broccoli", "squash"), "vegetable", 
     ifelse(col1 %in% c("tundra", grepl("grassland", col1)), "biome", NA))))
```

Comment: It's simpler to use `case_when`: `df %>% mutate(col2 = case_when(grepl('cat|dog', col1) ~ 'animal', grepl('carrot|broccoli|squash', col1) ~ 'vegetable', grepl('tundra|grassland', col1) ~ 'biome'))` or a lookup table

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`grepl` returns a logical vector, you need `grep(..., value=TRUE)`:

```
df %>% 
    mutate(col2 = ifelse(col1 %in% c("dog", grep("cat", col1, value=T)), "animal", 
                  ifelse(col1 %in% c(grep("carrot", col1, value=T), "broccoli", "squash"), "vegetable", 
                  ifelse(col1 %in% c("tundra", grep("grassland", col1, value=T)), "biome", NA))))

#         col1      col2
#1         cat    animal
#2        cats    animal
#3        cat2    animal
#4         dog    animal
#5      carrot vegetable
#6     carrots vegetable
#7    broccoli vegetable
#8      squash vegetable
#9      tundra     biome
#10  grassland     biome
#11 grasslands     biome
```

Comment: Great thanks. I had tried grep instead of grepl but didn't know about the value=T.